# node-mongodb-native: storing references to IDs

Tags: mongodb, node.js

What is the best way to store references to IDs with the node-mongodb-native driver?

I am currently storing an ID like 4e2675b04aa5520000000002 on its own. Should I instead be storing ObjectID('4e2675b04aa5520000000002')?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ID is actually a mongo ObjectId (meaning, the "4e2675b04aa5520000000002" is actually one) then it is much more efficient to store it as such rather than a string, both in terms of size and performance.

Note that there's actually a reference convention defined as well, details here : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-DBRef

Most drivers will allow you to automatically retrieve the referred documents without manually having to query for them. Since that's behaviour that can get in the way I think it's usually preferred to just store ObjectId("4e2675b04aa5520000000002") as the value as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

do you have to use your own IDs? mongodb creates them for you if you don't supply them (_id). if you have to set them manually, then use ObjectID and save them in _id.

Comment: generally your driver will create the _id for you, so it is still generated client side. This is actually the best practice as it results in more unique identifiers. ObjectId generation in mongodb uses machine specific information when possible. See the following for more details: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs